# Why is my jquery not making Ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Server side code is irrelevant at this point because no request is coming through, so the issue must be client side and since I don't know much js - I assume there problem is there.  What am I doing wrong?

html

```
<input type='button' onclick='UpdateStatus()' value='Status Update'>
```

js

```
<script>
    function UpdateStatus() {
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"/edit_view/",
            data: {
                product:"test",
                platform:"test",
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
            success: function() {
                console.log(data($data));
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Also can't get anything to log to chrome dev console - I don't know why..

Comment: Where do you set the variables `product` and `platform`?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: for the sake of getting antyhing working here - im updating those variables to just be strings

Comment: nothing is being output to javascript console

Comment: Does the Network tab show the request being sent?

Comment: nothing in console, no requests sent in network

Comment: Are you sure the function is even being called? Add `console.log("Sending AJAX");`

Comment: okay now it shows UpdateStatus not defined in the console

Comment: I'll bet anything you defined the function inside another function. `onclick` can only access the global scope.

Comment: I'll bet you defined it inside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: yea i did - fixing now

Comment: im using the exact code above and same issue

Comment: i removed all js except for what is in the OP

Comment: Check for typos, especially correct capitalization. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: okay im passed that error although now im getting 'data is undefined' in the console.log part

Comment: it was a typo lol

Comment: You're trying to call a function named `data()`. Have you defined that function?

Comment: And what is `$data`? You never declared that variable.

Comment: i am just trying to return whatever is in the response of the request.  i saw an example that had $data in there

Comment: `success: function(data) { console.log(data); }`

Comment: Really!!!!?, move in chat or delete comments above. be kind, this is too long comments feed

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the success callback doesnt have a parameter for example

```
<script>
    function UpdateStatus(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"/edit_view/",
            data: {
                product:"test",
                platform:"test",
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data($data));
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

if it does not work check your network tab on google chrome developers tools if there is something happening there

Comment: yea that was a problem too that i fixed - i think my console is just broke though, i can't get anything to log in it

Comment: check if your browser is up to date if not update it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included the jquery library first. 
`$.ajax` function is available only when you included the jquery library. You can only do xml http requests to achieve ajax call using plain javascript.

Try by including any of the latest jquery library version :

Ex:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now try

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"/edit_view/",
    data: {
        product:"test",
        platform:"test",
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
    },               
    success: function(data) {           
        console.log(data($data));
    }
});
```

Now when you check in your console atleast the ajax call will be generate. If any issues exists after that, then it will be with the `url:"/edit_view/",` and need to provide an appropriate path.